React Native project stopped working after upgrading to XCode 15.2
My React Native project was working fine on the XCode 14 series. But since now we have to upgrade the iOS SDK, I had to update the XCode to 15.2
Since then, my build has failed. Following is the error trace.

Showing All Errors Only
Build target RTApp of project RTApp with configuration Debug
/Users/nimila/projects/rt-app/RTApp/ios/RTApp.xcodeproj: warning: The
iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to
11.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 12.0 to 17.2.99. (in target 'RTApp' from project 'RTApp') warning: Run script build phase 'Start Packager' will be run during every build because it
does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add
output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in
every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script
phase. (in target 'RTApp' from project 'RTApp') warning: Run script
build phase 'Bundle React Native code and images' will be run during
every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this
warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or
configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency
analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'RTApp' from project
'RTApp') warning: Run script build phase '[CP-User] [RNFB] Core
Configuration' will be run during every build because it does not
specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output
dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every
build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script
phase. (in target 'RTApp' from project 'RTApp')
Ld
/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RTApp.app/RTApp
normal (in target 'RTApp' from project 'RTApp')
cd /Users/nimila/projects/rt-app/RTApp/ios
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
-Xlinker -reproducible -target x86_64-apple-ios11.0-simulator -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator17.2.sdk
-O0 -L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/EagerLinkingTBDs/Debug-iphonesimulator
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
-L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator
-L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator17.2.sdk/usr/lib/swift
-L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AppAuth
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/BVLinearGradient
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DoubleConversion
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBReactNativeSpec
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBSDKCoreKit
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBSDKLoginKit
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBSDKShareKit
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseCore
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseCoreInternal
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseInstallations
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Folly
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GCDWebServer
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GTMAppAuth
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GTMSessionFetcher
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleSignIn
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PromisesObjC
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCTTypeSafety
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNAppleAuthentication
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNCAsyncStorage
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNCCheckbox
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNCPicker
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNCPushNotificationIOS
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNDateTimePicker
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNDeviceInfo
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNFBAnalytics
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNFBApp
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNGoogleSignin
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNI18n
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNSVG
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNVectorIcons
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-Core
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-CoreModules
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTAnimation
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTBlob
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTImage
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTLinking
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTNetwork
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTSettings
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTText
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTVibration
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-cxxreact
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-jsi
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-jsiexecutor
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-jsinspector
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactCommon
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReactNativeART
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RealmJS
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Yoga
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/glog
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-blur
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-fbsdk-next
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-navigator-ios
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-netinfo
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-network-info
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-restart
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-safe-area-context
-L/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-webview
-L/Users/nimila/projects/rt-app/RTApp/ios/Pods/../../node_modules/realm/vendor/realm-ios
-L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator17.2.sdk/usr/lib/swift
-F/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/EagerLinkingTBDs/Debug-iphonesimulator
-F/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
-F/Users/nimila/projects/rt-app/RTApp/ios/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks
-F/Users/nimila/projects/rt-app/RTApp/ios/Pods/GoogleAppMeasurement/Frameworks
-F/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/FirebaseAnalytics/AdIdSupport
-F/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/GoogleAppMeasurement/AdIdSupport
-F/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/XCFrameworkIntermediates/GoogleAppMeasurement/WithoutAdIdSupport
-filelist /Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/RTApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RTApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RTApp.LinkFileList
-Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /usr/lib/swift -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto
-Xlinker /Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/RTApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RTApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RTApp_lto.o
-Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator
-L/usr/lib/swift -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/RTApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RTApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RTApp.swiftmodule
-ObjC -lAppAuth -lBVLinearGradient -lDoubleConversion -lFBReactNativeSpec -lFBSDKCoreKit -lFBSDKLoginKit -lFBSDKShareKit -lFirebaseCore -lFirebaseCoreInternal -lFirebaseInstallations -lFolly -lGCDWebServer -lGTMAppAuth -lGTMSessionFetcher -lGoogleSignIn -lGoogleUtilities -lPromisesObjC -lRCTTypeSafety -lRNAppleAuthentication -lRNCAsyncStorage -lRNCCheckbox -lRNCPicker -lRNCPushNotificationIOS -lRNDateTimePicker -lRNDeviceInfo -lRNFBAnalytics -lRNFBApp -lRNGoogleSignin -lRNI18n -lRNSVG -lRNVectorIcons -lReact-Core -lReact-CoreModules -lReact-RCTAnimation -lReact-RCTBlob -lReact-RCTImage -lReact-RCTLinking -lReact-RCTNetwork -lReact-RCTSettings -lReact-RCTText -lReact-RCTVibration -lReact-cxxreact -lReact-jsi -lReact-jsiexecutor -lReact-jsinspector -lReactCommon -lReactNativeART -lRealmJS -lYoga -lc++ -lglog -lnanopb -lreact-native-blur -lreact-native-fbsdk-next -lreact-native-navigator-ios -lreact-native-netinfo -lreact-native-network-info -lreact-native-restart -lreact-native-safe-area-context -lreact-native-webview -lrealm-ios -lrealm-parser-ios -lsqlite3 -lstdc++ -lz -framework AudioToolbox -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreText -framework FirebaseAnalytics -framework Foundation -framework GoogleAppMeasurement -framework GoogleAppMeasurementIdentitySupport
-framework JavaScriptCore -framework LocalAuthentication -framework MobileCoreServices -framework QuartzCore -framework SafariServices
-framework Security -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -weak_framework Accelerate -weak_framework Accounts -weak_framework AdSupport -weak_framework AudioToolbox -weak_framework AuthenticationServices -weak_framework CoreGraphics -weak_framework
Foundation -weak_framework QuartzCore -weak_framework Security
-weak_framework Social -weak_framework StoreKit -weak_framework UIKit -ObjC -lc++ -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/RTApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RTApp.build/RTApp.app-Simulated.xcent
-Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __ents_der -Xlinker /Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/RTApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RTApp.build/RTApp.app-Simulated.xcent.der
-lPods-RTApp -Xlinker -no_adhoc_codesign -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/RTApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RTApp.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/RTApp_dependency_info.dat
-o /Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RTApp.app/RTApp
ld: warning: ignoring duplicate libraries: '-lc++' ld: warning: object
file
(/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libPods-RTApp.a2)
was built for newer 'iOS-simulator' version (16.1) than being linked
(11.0) duplicate symbol
'OBJC_IVAR$_RCTUIImageViewAnimated._maxBufferCount' in:
/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTImage/libReact-RCTImage.a17
/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTImage/libReact-RCTImage.a16
duplicate symbol 'OBJC_CLASS$_RCTUIImageViewAnimated' in:
/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTImage/libReact-RCTImage.a17
/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTImage/libReact-RCTImage.a16
duplicate symbol
'OBJC_IVAR$_RCTUIImageViewAnimated._currentFrameIndex' in:
/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTImage/libReact-RCTImage.a17
/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTImage/libReact-RCTImage.a16
duplicate symbol 'OBJC_IVAR$_RCTUIImageViewAnimated._animatedImage'
in:
/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTImage/libReact-RCTImage.a17
/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTImage/libReact-RCTImage.a16
duplicate symbol 'OBJC_IVAR$_RCTUIImageViewAnimated._currentFrame'
in:
/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTImage/libReact-RCTImage.a17
/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTImage/libReact-RCTImage.a16
duplicate symbol 'OBJC_IVAR$_RCTUIImageViewAnimated._fetchQueue' in:
/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTImage/libReact-RCTImage.a17
/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTImage/libReact-RCTImage.a16
duplicate symbol
'OBJC_IVAR$_RCTUIImageViewAnimated._totalFrameCount' in:
/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTImage/libReact-RCTImage.a17
/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTImage/libReact-RCTImage.a16
duplicate symbol
'OBJC_IVAR$_RCTUIImageViewAnimated._animatedImageScale' in:
/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTImage/libReact-RCTImage.a17
/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTImage/libReact-RCTImage.a16
duplicate symbol 'OBJC_IVAR$_RCTUIImageViewAnimated._frameBuffer'
in:
/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTImage/libReact-RCTImage.a17
/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTImage/libReact-RCTImage.a16
duplicate symbol 'OBJC_METACLASS$_RCTUIImageViewAnimated' in:
/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTImage/libReact-RCTImage.a17
/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTImage/libReact-RCTImage.a16
duplicate symbol
'OBJC_IVAR$_RCTUIImageViewAnimated._currentLoopCount' in:
/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTImage/libReact-RCTImage.a17
/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTImage/libReact-RCTImage.a16
duplicate symbol 'OBJC_IVAR$_RCTUIImageViewAnimated._currentTime'
in:
/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTImage/libReact-RCTImage.a17
/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTImage/libReact-RCTImage.a16
duplicate symbol 'OBJC_IVAR$_RCTUIImageViewAnimated._maxBufferSize'
in:
/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTImage/libReact-RCTImage.a17
/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTImage/libReact-RCTImage.a16
duplicate symbol 'OBJC_IVAR$_RCTUIImageViewAnimated._lock' in:
/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTImage/libReact-RCTImage.a17
/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTImage/libReact-RCTImage.a16
duplicate symbol 'OBJC_IVAR$_RCTUIImageViewAnimated._bufferMiss' in:
/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTImage/libReact-RCTImage.a17
/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTImage/libReact-RCTImage.a16
duplicate symbol 'OBJC_IVAR$_RCTUIImageViewAnimated._totalLoopCount'
in:
/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTImage/libReact-RCTImage.a17
/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTImage/libReact-RCTImage.a16
duplicate symbol 'OBJC_IVAR$_RCTUIImageViewAnimated._displayLink'
in:
/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTImage/libReact-RCTImage.a17
/Users/nimila/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RTApp-agpmnijgmkcecievpzkyxidjmtbx/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/React-RCTImage/libReact-RCTImage.a16
ld: 17 duplicate symbols clang: error: linker command failed with exit
code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
17 duplicate symbols
Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Build failed    2024-04-17, 6:11 PM    203.9 seconds

The first part of the issue regarding the IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET was resolved. But for the rest, I can't figure out the "17 duplicate symbols" issue.
My package.json:
{
  "name": "RTApp",
  "version": "2.40.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication": "^1.1.2",
    "@react-native-community/art": "^1.2.0",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.9.0",
    "@react-native-community/blur": "^3.6.0",
    "@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.7",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^3.0.9",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^5.8.0",
    "@react-native-community/picker": "^1.6.1",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.1.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^17.4.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^17.4.2",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^9.0.2",
    "create-react-class": "^15.6.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "moment-duration-format": "^2.3.2",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.28",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-native": "0.62.2",
    "react-native-a": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-carousel-view": "^0.5.1",
    "react-native-device-info": "^10.11.0",
    "react-native-dropdownalert": "^4.2.1",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.2.7",
    "react-native-fbsdk-next": "^4.6.0",
    "react-native-gifted-spinner": "^0.1.0",
    "react-native-htmlview": "^0.15.0",
    "react-native-i18n": "^2.0.15",
    "react-native-image-carousel": "^0.4.6",
    "react-native-kenburns-view": "^4.1.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-spacer": "^0.4.1",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-map-link": "^2.7.27",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^9.1.0",
    "react-native-modal-selector": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-navbar": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-navigator-ios": "git://github.com/nHiRanZ/react-native-navigator-ios.git",
    "react-native-network-info": "^5.2.1",
    "react-native-progress": "^4.1.2",
    "react-native-qrcode-svg": "^6.0.3",
    "react-native-radio-buttons": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-responsive-keyboard-view": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-restart": "0.0.19",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-view": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-side-menu": "^1.1.3",
    "react-native-simple-gauge": "^0.2.3",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
    "react-native-star-rating": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.23.1",
    "react-phone-number-input": "^3.1.10",
    "react-timeout": "^1.2.0",
    "realm": "^4.0.0-beta.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.9.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.9.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "0.0.5",
    "babel-jest": "24.9.0",
    "eslint": "6.8.0",
    "jest": "24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.58.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.11.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}

Please assist.
